# Why x.push[0] did not produce an error?

Tags: javascript

I made a typo, use `x.push[0]` instead of `x.push(0)`. But it did not produce an error and returned `undefined` which make me very confused.

[image: test]

Comment: x.push is a function ... in javascript functions are objects too ... [0] accesses the property named `0` on an object, not having such a property is not an error, it just returns `undefined` ... therefore, no error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b.push` is a function, but functions are just another kind of value – and the `[]` operator can *attempt* to access properties on any kind of value. If the property isn’t found, though, the result will be `undefined`, and that’s the case here; functions don’t normally have a `0` property.

```
var b = [];
var someFunction = b.push;

console.log('0' in someFunction);  // false; function doesn’t have a 0 property
console.log(someFunction[0]);      // undefined for the same reason

console.log('length' in someFunction);  // true; functions have a length property!
console.log(someFunction['length']);    // 1; just like someFunction.length
```

Comment: I like your wording better so I am going to delete my answer in favor of yours.

Comment: But why `someFunction.0` will return `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number` ?

Comment: @Tina: When using dot access for properties, the property name can't start with a digit. Similarly, `[1, 2, 3][0]` works, but `[1, 2, 3].0` doesn’t.